# Is this character affected by the enchantment on Aurora?

Tags: maleficent

At the christening of Aurora, one of the pixies wishes that Aurora will grow up being loved by everyone she meets. Before cursing her, Maleficent confirms the pixie's wish/spell.

Over the course of the movie,

> Maleficent comes to love Aurora.

Is this because of the enchantment, or is it meant to be

> innate goodness lost/ignored by Maleficent?

Comment: +1- I am such a slow learner, but finally I understand what you mean. Lol.

Comment: @アズーサIs the question unclear? Any ideas how I may be able to convey it better?

Comment: @phantom42- Not unclear, just for me it was until I read it a couple more times. :)

Answer (score 5):

Since it was not immediate, it would seem that it wasn't enchantment.

Also

> In most fairy tales, "True Love" can not be an enchantment, and "True Love's Kiss" would never work under a spell.  It must be that Maleficent grew to truly love Aurora in her heart, otherwise the spell could not have been broken.  It is also a better character arc, from a story-telling standpoint, to believe that Aurora's goodness rekindled the goodness that was buried in Maleficent.

Comment: The true love may have been something that grew, but was the initial turn from outright hatred of Aurora only because of the enchantment?

Comment: Maybe?  I can't find a source for the script (I'm behind a firewall at work), hopefully it might have insight. I tend to think that if it was the enchantment, it would have been instant, and therefore the enchantment isn't the major factor, but I have nothing to back that up.